# Cannonball Simulation

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with this current program.

1. the exact velocity seems alright, but the experimental velocity at 50 seconds on the first second is supposed to be 45.144 and the simulation is supposed to take 10.21 seconds rather than 10.18, is there something wrong in my for loop? I just started learning about C++ so I am not very good in most areas of the subject.

```
/*
 Suppose a cannonball is propelled vertically into the air with a starting 
 velocity of v0. A physics
 the textbook would give the position of the ball after t seconds as:
 (1) s(t) = −0.5 · g · t^2 + v0 · t
 where g is the gravitational force of the earth, and g = 9.81 m/sec2
 .

 We will confirm equation 1 by a simulation. In our simulation, we will consider how the ball
 moves in very short time intervals ∆t. In a short time interval, the velocity v is nearly constant,
 and we can compute the distance the ball moves as ∆s = v · ∆t.
 In our program, we can set a variable deltaT = 0.01 and update the position by

 s = s + v * deltaT;

 The velocity changes constantly: it is reduced by the gravitational force of the earth. In a short
 time interval, v decreases by g · ∆t, and we must keep the velocity updated as

 v = v - g * deltaT;

 In the next iteration the new velocity is used to update the distance.
 Now run the simulation until the cannonball falls back to the earth. Set the initial velocity
 to a value between 50 m/s and 150 m/s. Update the position and velocity 100 times per second,
 but only print out the experimental position every full second, along with the value from the exact
 formula (equation 1), for comparison. At the end, print the final time t when the ball hits the
 ground.

 1. How The Program Works
 The program prompts the user for the initial velocity; if the velocity given is not between 50 and
 150 m/s (inclusive), keep asking the user until a valid value is input. Allow the user to run as many
 simulations as they want.

 2. Requirements
 • Your program should be named cannonball.cpp and compile on erdos.
 • If the user enters an invalid initial velocity, continue to prompt until a valid number is
 provided.
 • Print out the initial velocity for each simulation.
 • For each elapsed second, print out the experimental position and the exact position.
 • At the end of the simulation, print out the final (i.e., total) time t.
 • Ask the user if they wish to run another simulation.
*/

/*
 10/10/2019
 This program runs a simulation of a cannonball getting shot out of a cannon. It calcuates the ball's height at various times.
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double deltaT = 0.01, G = 9.81;
    double v, vExact, t = 0, totT=0, s1 = 0, s2, temp;
    char choice;
    bool again = true;

    do{
        cout << "Enter an initial velocity between 50 and 150m/s." << endl;
        cin >> v;
        while (v < 50 || v > 150)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry, try again." << endl;
            cin >> v;
        }
        cout << "Begin simulation: " << endl << "v0 = " << v << "m/s" << endl;
        if (v > 50 || v < 150)
        {
            vExact = v;
            do{
                for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
                {
                    v = v - G * deltaT;
                    s1 = s1 + v * deltaT;
                    t += 0.01;
                    if (s1 > -.25 && s1 <= 0)
                        totT = t;
                }
                s2 = ((-0.5)*G*(t*t))+(vExact*t);
                if(s1 > 0)
                    cout << "The experimental position at " << t << " seconds  is " << s1 << "m" << endl;
                if(s2 > 0)
                    cout << "The exact (formula) position at " << t << " seconds is " << s2 << "m" << endl;
                temp = s1;
            } while (temp > 0 && s2 > 0);
            cout << "Total time = " << totT << endl;
            cout << "Run another simulation? [Y]es or [N]o" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 'Y':
                    again = true;
                    t = 0;
                    s1 = 0;
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    again = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    again = false;
                    break;
            }
       }
    }while (again);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm no physics expert but i think you need to use trigonometry and as for the loop what are your errors?

Comment: I don't need to use trigonometry because this is a course type of requirement and we haven't reached this, the loop part is fixed on my end.

Comment: so this simulation is supposed to calculate the ball's height after being shot out from a cannon?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables as they get computed, on each step: what observations did you make, and at which point did the calculations diverge from the expected results, and why? This is exactly what a debugger is for. Did you run this in your debugger already, and if not why not?

Comment: @jakHunter Correct, after each full second.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I use vim, I have no idea if it has a debugger, however, I know that I probably need to do something with DeltaT to get my desired variable.

Comment: If you use Vim as your editor, you can probably use GDB as your debugger.  Search the internet for "VIM c++ debugger".

Comment: I don't believe my program has any bugs, I think this is a logic error on my part as I do not yet know how to calculate DeltaT to my experimental position in my loop

Comment: @AdamFaid If your program has no bugs, then it works as intended. You said it does not work as intended. Therefore, it has at least one bug. (A logic error on your part would most likely result in a logic error -- a.k.a. a bug -- in the program.) A debugger can help you find it, as can streaming diagnostics to `cout` or `cerr`.

Comment: You could use an IDE with integrated debugger, e.g. VS Code, Eclipse CDT, Visual Studio. Or learn how to use a standalone debugger like gdb. There are frontends to make it simpler, e.g. ddd or cgdb. Another tool is [radare2](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/debugger/intro.html) but it's probably to complex to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is right man. its just that some lines are at the wrong position.

make sure you have these two statements in this order:

```
s1 = s1 + v * deltaT; 
v = v - G * deltaT;
```

and also:

```
//if (s1 >(-0.25) && s1 <= 0)
```

change the above line with this:

```
if (s1 >(-0.25) )
    totT = t;
```